# How can i not repeat this function

Tags: jquery, html, dry

I have a filtering system on my blog, it works fine, but im just wondering how i can not repeat this function over and over.

heres the html:

```
<div class="postFilter">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="filter filter1 filterActive">all</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="filter filter2">another link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="filter filter3">third link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="filter filter4">fourth</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="filter filter5">fifth</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /.postFilter -->
```

and the jquery i am using:

```
$('.filter1').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    // add & Remove filter

    $('.filter').removeClass('filterActive');
    $('.filter1').addClass('filterActive');

    // hide & show categories

    $('.categ').hide();
    $('.categ1').show();
});

$('.filter2').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    // add & Remove filter

    $('.filter').removeClass('filterActive');
    $('.filter2').addClass('filterActive');

    // hide & show categories

    $('.categ').hide();
    $('.categ2').show();
});
```

i repeat this 5 times, i know what i want to do, i want to see if the filter clicked is equal to 1,2,3,4,5 then show the code for the responding function. but im not sure where to start.

Forgot to mention i have tried this:

```
var filterNum;

$('.filter').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    if($('.filter').hasClass('filter1')){
        filterNum = 1;
    }else if($('.filter').hasClass('filter2')){
        filterNum = 2;
    }else if($('.filter').hasClass('filter3')){
        filterNum = 3;
    }else if($('.filter').hasClass('filter4')){
        filterNum = 4;
    }else if($('.filter').hasClass('filter5')){
        filterNum = 5;
    }

    filterClick(filterNum);
});



function filterClick(number){
    // add & Remove filter

    $('.filter').removeClass('filterActive');
    $('.filter' + number).addClass('filterActive');

    // hide & show categories

    $('.categ').hide();
    $('.categ' + number).show();
}
```

Comment: Your attempt is close, however instead of using `$('.filter').hasClass()`, you probably want `$(this).hasClass()`.

Comment: Glad to hear it. While your idea works, I personally like empiric's answer below. Using data attributes is a nice and clean way to avoid your giant `if / else` portion. You want to write your code so that you can have 99 filters and not have to touch it, which the `data` method achieves, whereas yours will require 94 more lines of code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `this` to refer to the clicked elemten. Additionally to that you can use a custom `data` attribute to reference to the categories you want to show:

```js
$('.filter').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  // add & Remove filter
  var $this = $(this);

  $('.filter').removeClass('filterActive');
  $this.addClass('filterActive');

  // hide & show categories
  $('.categ').hide();
  $('.' + $this.data('cat')).show();
});
```

```css
.filterActive {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="postFilter">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="filter filterActive" data-cat="categ1">all</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="filter" data-cat="categ2">another link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="filter" data-cat="categ3">third link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="filter" data-cat="categ4">fourth</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="filter" data-cat="categ5">fifth</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="cat">
  <div class="categ categ1">
    Cat1
  </div>
  <div class="categ categ2">
    Cat2
  </div>
  <div class="categ categ3">
    Cat3
  </div>
  <div class="categ categ4">
    Cat4
  </div>
  <div class="categ categ5">
    Cat5
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This could be improved, as you are using a JQuery selector inside a click event, it will have to make that selection everytime you click, which is un-necessary, and not performant

Answer (score 0):

```
var $filters = $('.filter');
var $filtered = $('.categ');

$filters.on('click', function(){
   $filters.removeClass('filterActive');
   $(this).addClass('filterActive'); 
   $filtered.removeClass('filterActive');
   $filtered.eq(k).addClass('filterActive');  
});
```

https://codepen.io/mrbizle/pen/vZKYgq

This way we don't have to create loads of jQuery objects

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify the html, I would use data-attributes to make this easier:

```
<div class="postFilter">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" data-filterid="1" class="filter filterActive">all</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-filterid="2" class="filter ">another link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-filterid="3" class="filter ">third link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-filterid="4" class="filter ">fourth</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-filterid="5" class="filter ">fifth</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /.postFilter -->
```

---

```
$('.filter').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $('.filter').removeClass('filterActive');
    $(this).addClass('filterActive');

    $('.categ').hide();
    $('.categ' + $(this).data('filterid')).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is this `.categ`? Assuming that it's inside the `<li>`, this should work:

```js
$('.filter').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // add & Remove filter
  $('.filter').removeClass('filterActive');
  $(this).addClass('filterActive');
  // hide & show categories
  $('.categ').hide();
  $(this).next('.categ').show();
  /* If .categ is inside the .filter, use this instead:
    $(this).find('.categ').show();
     And if .categ is outside, you'll need to use something like:
    $(this).parents().next('.categ').show();
  */
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="postFilter">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="filter filter1 filterActive">all</a><span class="categ categ1" style="display: none;">categ</span></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="filter filter2">another link</a><span class="categ categ2" style="display: none;">categ</span></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="filter filter3">third link</a><span class="categ categ3" style="display: none;">categ</span></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="filter filter4">fourth</a><span class="categ categ4" style="display: none;">categ</span></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="filter filter5">fifth</a><span class="categ categ5" style="display: none;">categ</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```